# To create a stored procedure for counting distinct values for 8 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a table product in which I have 8 columns and I have to count the distinct values. To achieve this, I need to create a stored procedure.

So, how to create it?

This is the sample I have wrote for two columns:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE GET_COUNT
( count_prod OUT INT,
count_partner OUT INT) IS
BEGIN
SELECT 
 count(*),
count(distinct(BUSINESS))
INTO 
count_prod,
count_partner from Product where ACTIVE Like 'Y'; 
END GET_COUNT;
```

Is this right or I have to do it using cursor?

Comment: you want `count` of `distinct values` of each column or only `Business` column. [assume you are using `oracle`]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Col01] CHAR(1)
   ,[Col02] TINYINT
   ,[Col03] CHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Col01], [Col02], [Col03])
VALUES ('A', 1, 'AAA')
      ,('A', 1, 'AAA')
      ,('A', 2, 'AAA')
      ,('B', 1, 'AAA')
      ,('B', 3, 'AAB')
      ,('A', 3, 'ACA');

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Col01]) AS [Col01Count]
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT [Col02]) AS [Col02Count]
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT [Col03]) AS [Col03Count]
FROM @DataSource;
```

The [COUNT](https://www.google.bg/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tsql%20count%20distint) aggregate (and most of the aggregate functions) supports a `DISTINCT` clause which should solve your issue.

Comment: @ApoorvJain This is a simple demonstration. Just use the last query - `COUNT (DISTINCT [YourColumn])` x 8 times :-)

Comment: thanks for your help .I am getting the required output. May u tell how I can  send that output in mail in table format (the output is in a table and send over email to my gmail account)?

Comment: @ApoorvJain You should either edit your question and add the new requirement or ask a separate question in order to get further help.